# A simple form component with react.js. But onsubmit all fields always empty?

Tags: reactjs

I am starting with react.js and I have this simple form but `onSubmit` the input fields are always empty?? Any tips/idea what I am overlooking?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class PostForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            userID: '',
            title: '',
            body: ''
        }
        
        // this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this);
    }

    changeHandler = e => {
        this.setState = ({ [e.target.name]: e.target.defaultValue })
    }

    submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state) //<-- always empty fields???
    }

    render() {
        const { userID, title, body } = this.state

        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="userID" defaultValue={userID} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="title" defaultValue={title} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="body" defaultValue={body} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PostForm
```

Comment: `this.setState` is a function and you're assigning it a variable.

Comment: @zhulien Sharp! I just change it but I still get empty values??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState` is a function and instead of calling it you're trying to assign a variable to it. Change your `changeHandler` function to:

```
changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState((state) => {
        return {
            ...state,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        };
    })
};
```

Also, like @Alex pointed out, you should add `value={<state-variable>}` to your inputs in order to make them controlled:

```
<input type="text" name="userID" value={userID} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
```

This will also cover your default value case as it will apply the initial values from your state anyway.

Comment: indeed all my errors were connected, by me putting a = after setState as I thought about a variable. Again tx!

Answer (score 1):

Here you set to state default value (it's emty). Change to `e.target.value`

```
changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState = ({ [e.target.name]: e.target.defaultValue })
   }
```

And change this `defaultValue={userID}` to `value={userID}` on every input

```
<input type="text" name="userID" defaultValue={userID} onChange= 
{this.changeHandler} />
```

Comment: hi, but I changed value={userID} to defaultValue={userID} as I couldn't see the text input. But that might be because I have setState as a variable and not as a function. I am going to try your suggestions. Tx in advance